# Trying to implement masonry on Bulma CSS

Tags: css, bulma

I'm trying to implement a masonry on Bulma CSS through cards, I want something like this:

[image]

And the css code detects the height of the card (If one card has more text, this height grows up...) I have this [example](https://codepen.io/montoyaandres/pen/MLRdRN?editors=1100) but I couldn't implement it...

The wrapper works through this code (If the screen is small change to 1 if not 2):

```
.masonry {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

Help please...

Comment: Basically, CSs is not suited to such layout except (possibly) CSS-Grid - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout

Comment: Do you have some example implementing what I'm doing with grid? Or any library... I'm using React with the real project...

Comment: Perhaps this? https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/tiles/

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar. Did you ever find a good technique for this using Bulma?